# Why do i get avc1.000000? (FFMPEG, H.264 Video Encoding, C++)

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I have a bunch of bitmaps, and need to make them encoded in h.264 in fragmented .mp4.
I'm using C++. 
What could cause that my AVC Profile is set to 0, SPS[], PPS[] and codec string to avc1.000000?

Output from the mp4info:

> File:
>
> > minor version:    200
> >     compatible brand: iso6
> >     compatible brand: mp41
> >     fast start:       yes
>
> Movie:
>
> > duration:   0 ms
> >     time scale: 1000
> >     fragments:  yes
>
> Found 1 Tracks
>
> > Track 1:
> >     flags:        3 ENABLED IN-MOVIE
> >     id:     1
> >     type:         Video
> >     duration: 0 ms
> >     language: und
> >
> > media:
> >
> > > sample count: 0
> > >       timescale:    90000
> > >       duration:     0 (media timescale units)
> > >       duration:     0 (ms)
> > >       bitrate (computed): 412.672 Kbps
> > >       sample count with fragments: 35
> > >       duration with fragments: 540000
> > >       duration with fragments: 6000 (ms)
> >
> > display width:  1280.000000
> >     display height: 720.000000
> >
> > Sample Description 0
> >
> > > Coding: avc1 (H.264)
> > >       Width:n 1280
> > >       Height: 720
> > >       Depth: 24
> > >       AVC Profile:          0
> > >       AVC Profile Compat:   0
> > >       AVC Level:            0
> > >       AVC NALU Length Size: 0
> > >       AVC SPS: []
> > >       AVC PPS: []
> > >       Codecs String: avc1.000000

I'm using things like

```
if (stream->codecpar->codec_id == AVCodecID.AV_CODEC_ID_H264)
{
    err = ffmpeg.av_opt_set(cctx->priv_data, "preset", "ultrafast", 0);
    err = ffmpeg.av_opt_set(cctx->priv_data, "tune", "zerolatency", 0);
    err = ffmpeg.av_opt_set(cctx->priv_data, "profile", "high", 0);
} 

...

AVDictionary* opts = null;
ffmpeg.av_dict_set(&opts, "movflags", "default_base_moof+frag_keyframe+empty_moov", 0); 

...

AVPacket* pPacket = ffmpeg.av_packet_alloc();
try
{
    int error;
    do
    {
        ffmpeg.avcodec_send_frame(cctx, &convertedFrame).ThrowExceptionIfError();

        error = ffmpeg.avcodec_receive_packet(cctx, pPacket);
    } while (error == ffmpeg.AVERROR(ffmpeg.EAGAIN));

    error.ThrowExceptionIfError();

}
finally
{
    ffmpeg.av_packet_rescale_ts(pPacket, cctx->time_base, stream->time_base);
    pPacket->stream_index = stream->index;

    ffmpeg.av_interleaved_write_frame(ofctx, pPacket);
    ffmpeg.av_packet_unref(pPacket);
}
```

What am I missing? I'm using examples from internet. Thought that if AVFrame is encoded (send_frame) with H264 with profiles and presets and received as AVPacket. It should be done automatically.

This is my first post, please be nice. Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: Also, there is avc=false and nal_length_size=0 in FFprobe. Do I have to put something in extradata of H264 codeccontext?

Comment: What I think is that my ffmpeg-libavcodec did't set the values for extradata and as I assume it should do that. When I set the extradata by hardcoded values of pps and sps it's better, but its not perfect. I should have set that by default  Any help will be great